Configuration Vitest in Nuxt 3
I have a large project made with Nuxt 3, Vue, Pinia, Axios, and TypeScript.
I need help with configuring Vitest to work in my project.
I've had many problems. For example, I wrote a test and it didn't recognize the components folder with ~/ or @/ etc.
Now I get this error when testing a function file with an (axios) API:
'Error: Nuxt instance unavailable'

Can you edit the question to add your vite.config and vitest.config file as a code snippet?

I think you might just have to add a resolve alias in file vite.config.js which will be picked up by vitest, for example:
export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
      },
    }
  });
}



I'm having an issue with a 'ref' error when accessing my components. Additionally, I'm encountering an 'Error: Nuxt instance unavailable' when accessing a function that uses the API."

It's kinda difficult to assist you without seeing what your code setup or relevant files are like
